# send ajax request to laravel controller to download a pdf

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pdf

I have table with a column for checkbox, When a certain button is clicked i send checked checkboxs with ajax request to a controller to download a pdf file after it has been made ,but unfortunately it doesn't fire the download box .i hope you help me out.

My Ajax :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(document).on('click', '#minvoice', function(event)
{
    //var alert = confirm('Are You Sure?');
    var checkedValues = $('#chkbx:checked').map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get();

    $.post('{{route('payments.multiple_invoices')}}', {'checkboxs' : checkedValues, '_token' : $('input[name=_token]').val() }, function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });

});
});
</script>
```

My Controller :

```
public function multiple_invoices(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isMethod('post')) 
    {   
        //export invoice
        $requestData[] = $request->checkboxs;
        $filenamepdf = public_path().'/export/invoices/multiple_invoices.pdf';
        $data = self::getMulInvoiceData($requestData);
        PDFHelper::export($data, $filenamepdf, true);
        return Response::download($filenamepdf, 'Multiple_invoice_'.date('Y-m-d').'_'. time().'.pdf', []);
    }
}

public static function getMulInvoiceData($requestData)
{
    $payments = UnitPayment::whereIn('id', $requestData)->get();
    return View::make('payments.mulInvoice', compact('payments'));
}
```

My Views:

```
<td><input id="chkbx" type="checkbox" value="{{ $payment->id }}" /></td>
```

MulInovices.blade.php :

```
@foreach($payments as $payment)
<div align="left" style="text-align: left;"><b>payment : {{$payment->id}}  </b></div>
@endforeach
```

My Route:

```
Route::any('payments/multiple_invoices', ['uses' => 'PaymentsController@multiple_invoices','as' => 'payments.multiple_invoices']);
```

i hope you tell me how to get this to work . thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
return Response::download($filenamepdf, 'Multiple_invoice_'.date('Y-m-d').'_'. time().'.pdf', []);
```

to

```
return Response::download($filenamepdf, 'Multiple_invoice_'.date('Y-m-d').'_'. time().'.pdf', ['Content-Type' => 'application/pdf']);
```

(Difference is code below is added in to third parameter [] of Response::download)

```
'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf'
```

If you are using Laravel 5+ you can use code below

```
response()->($filenamepdf, 'Multiple_invoice_'.date('Y-m-d').'_'. time().'.pdf', ['Content-Type' => 'application/pdf']);
```

What we did is add headers to recognise response as a pdf file.

Comment: thanks Yusuf , i tried what you have told me but still i can't see the download box , i think i should write something insdie $.post({/here}); !

Comment: I misunderstanded you, sorry. I thought file is not downloading. But I am not seeing any download button in your code.

Comment: there is a button when clicked the ajax request will be send to the controller but it doesn't return the proper response which is the download box 
here is my button/a : <a  id="minvoice">{{__('Print Multiple Invoices')}}</a>

Comment: The data is being printed to console.

Comment: I am not sure but add `$('$minvoice').attr('href', data);` below `console.log(data);`
And if you can print things in console to here, it will be nice.

Comment: before adding this part of code it was returning an object of the file in the console on a shape of unreadable chars , after adding this piece of code it redirects me to " Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.".

Comment: Can you post what it returns?

Comment: %PDF-1.7
%����
10 0 obj
<< /Type /Page /Parent 1 0 R /LastModified (D:20180124152520+02'00') /Resources 2 0 R /MediaBox [0.000000 0.000000 595.276000 841.890000] /CropBox [0.000000 0.000000 595.276000 841.890000] /BleedBox [0.000000 0.000000 595.276000 841.890000] /TrimBox [0.000000 0.000000 595.276000 841.890000] /ArtBox [0.000000 0.000000 595.276000 841.890000] /Contents 11 0 R /Rotate 0 /Group << /Type /Group /S /Transparency /CS /DeviceRGB >> /Annots [ 9 0 R ] /PZ 1 >>
end

Comment: Try returning `$filenamepdf` only instead of `Response::download` Then replace `console.log(data);` with `$('#minvoice').attr('href', data).attr('download', 'Multiple_invoice.pdf');`

Comment: it redirects me to a page content : Firefox can’t find the file at http://localhost/var/www/html/new-e-profit/public/export/invoices/multiple_invoices.pdf although it's the file location

Comment: Try to get what is coming from 'data' now.

Comment: thnx JO ^^ i really appreciate your help

Comment: You can show me your thanks by giving upvote, marking my answer as accepted and writing what you have done lastly to help other people what is going on.

Comment: well your answer did not solve my prob so it wont be accepted , but in the end i managed to send my checkboxs through a get form and capture it in the controller through get super global and that's it because ajax and download are rarely used together . thanks anyway.

Comment: No problem, you can add that as answer to your question and accept it then. People can see it easier.